# MessageEmbed field values may not be empty. Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a code that sends a random picture from a subreddit, from the weekly top.
But I receive the following error when I am trying to use the command:

```
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

Code:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "!foto") {
        const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');
        try {
            const {
                body
            } = await snekfetch
                .get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gtavcustoms.json?sort=top&t=week')
                .query({
                    limit: 10
                });
            const allowed = message.channel.nsfw ? body.data.children : body.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.over_18);
            if (!allowed.length) return message.channel.send('Het lijkt erop dat de nieuwe fotos op zijn, probeer het later nog eens!');
            const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x00A2E8)
                .setTitle(allowed[randomnumber].data.title)
                .setDescription("Gepost door: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.author)
                .setImage(allowed[randomnumber].data.url)
                .addField("Overige informatie:", "Likes: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.ups + " / Comments: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.num_comments)
            .setFooter("DaddyCoolNL Official Discord Server")
            message.channel.send(embed)
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more infomation about errors

Comment: Can you log your `allowed` array and check if its empty?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simple fix, but may not work. What you can try is putting it in backticks.

```
.addField("Overige informatie:", `Likes: ${allowed[randomnumber].data.ups + " / Comments: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.num_comments)}`
```

It also may be due to the allowed array not being complete, or something is off with it.